# How to combine multiple SQL queries CREATE, SELECT and UPDATE in one statement

Tags: sql, subquery

Step 1: I need to create a temporary table raw_data

```
CREATE TABLE #raw_data   ###create temporary table raw_data
AS 
    SELECT table1.*, ba.col2, ''::text as newcol 
    FROM table2 ba ##select column from table1 and table2 (alias ba) and add newcol to temporary table
    INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.id = table1.id;  ##inner join
```

Step 2: Update the raw_table first time

```
UPDATE raw_data c
SET newcol = 'fruit'
FROM table3.fruit f
WHERE f.ID = 1;
```

Step 3: Update the raw_table second time

```
UPDATE raw_data c
SET newcol = 'dryfruit'
FROM table4.dryfruit d
WHERE d.ID = 2;
```

Is there a way that the queries in step 1, 2 and 3 can be written in a single statement and `SELECT * FROM ....`  the final updated table?

Comment: What RDBMS are you talking about? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: This update syntax looks like SQL Server, but if it is, then the tables are not correlated in the statements. This means you end up with *all* raw_data.newcol = 'dryfruit' (provided there exists a row with ID = 2 in the table4.dryfruit table). Is this what you want? Or are you using another DBMS that works differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Merge statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

The syntax for it is easy but you can find examples and documentation about it.

Small sample:

```
MERGE tableToUpdate tu
USING newData nd ON tu.id = nd.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET tu.something = nd.something;
```